# Fetching a Page of data on an entity with a composite key

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an entity that defines a composite primary key through the use of `@IdClass`, however I get a syntax error (MSSQL) when trying to fetch a Page of data from this table.

Entity;

```
@IdClass(HoldCustodian.HoldCustodianKey.class)
public class HoldCustodian implements Serializable {
   
    @Version
    private Long lockCount;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Hold hold;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    // ETC

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public static class HoldCustodianKey implements Serializable {
        private Long hold;
        private Long user;
    }
```

Repository;

```
public interface HoldCustodianRepository extends JpaRepository<HoldCustodian, HoldCustodian.HoldCustodianKey>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<HoldCustodian> {}
```

When trying to execute [findAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-), I get a syntax error as the generated query is attempting to add both columns to the generated query (which is invalid in MSSQL)

```
select distinct count(distinct holdcustod0_.hold_sid, holdcustod0_.user_sid) as col_0_0_ from sec.HoldCustodian holdcustod0_ inner join sec.Hold hold1_ on holdcustod0_.hold_sid=hold1_.sid where hold1_.sid=2
```

```
SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
2021-05-25 15:38:34.577 ERROR 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near ','.
2021-05-25 15:38:34.585 ERROR 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.i.b.v.ValidationExceptionHandler       : Data layer exception: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2021-05-25 15:38:34.586 ERROR 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I either need to `SELECT COUNT(*)` or perhaps my mappings are incorrect?

Comment: I think that combination of `@EmbeddedId` and `@MapsId` will work better in your case, thus provides access to both, raw primary keys (Long-s) and their corresponding entities (Hold and User) from within entity. It will also simplify Criteria creation (seeing your repository is `JpaSpecificationExecutor`). Also don't forget to change your repository from `JpaRepository` to `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out the main issue was the use of `distinct` in the generated query, it makes sense that when using that the count query uses the PK instead of just `count(*)`! For my use of this entity, distinct will not be required. As for `JPARepository` - due to queries not listed this is correct for me to use.